# URL Rewrite Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewriting

Morning All,

I have classified ads with various categories and sub categories and I want to do a url rewrite using IIS7.  I need to make up a regular expression that could possibly have up to 5 categories and sub categories for example:

http://westpalmbeach.storeboard.com/classifieds/for-sale/electronics/looking-for-a-cheap-touchscreen-laptop/390

or

http://tampa.storeboard.com/classifieds/jobs/work-from-home/social-media-networker/380

notice the numerical value at the end of each url, this is the part I am interested in retrieving as it is the ID for the eventual URL which would be:

http://tampa.storeboard.com/classifieds/viewad.asp?RegionID=23&ClassAdID=390

How can I create a regular expression that can hunt out the integer on the end and also extract the domain name e.g. tampa.storeboard.com

Many thanks for your help.

Best Regards,
Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^http://([^/]+).*?(\d+)$
```

group 1 for domain name , and group 2 is for ID. It has been tested with [RAD regular expression designer](http://www.radsoftware.com.au/regexdesigner/).

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond REQUEST_URI !/classifieds/viewad.asp
RewriteRule /classifieds/.*/(\d*)$ /classifieds/viewad.asp?Region=%{HTTP_HOST}&ClassAdID=$1
```